# How to combine Conditions in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, conditional-statements, jooq

I have a list of conditions:

```
List<Condition> conditions = ...;
```

What is the easiest way to and-combine (or or-combine) these conditions into a new condition?

```
Condition condition = and(conditions);
```

Does JOOQ have a utility function for this? I agree it is easy to write, but I would rather not re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.6+ solution.

You can simply write:

```
Condition condition = DSL.and(conditions);
```

#### Prior to jOOQ 3.6:

Before this was implemented in jOOQ 3.6 ([#3904](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3904)) you had to resort to writing your own method:

```
static Condition and(Collection<? extends Condition> conditions) {
    Condition result = DSL.trueCondition();

    for (Condition condition : conditions)
        result = result.and(condition);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will implement like this and start using the built-in function once 3.6 is released. Great work!